# How to solve the following integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Can I ask how to solve the following integral

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-Ay}}{y^{B} \left( Cy + D \right)}dy$$

where $A, B, C$ and $D$ are positive constants.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-A y}}{y^B (C y + D)}{\rm d}y = C^{B-1} D^{-B} \Gamma (1-B) e^{\frac{A D}{C}} \Gamma \left(B,\frac{A
   D}{C}\right), ~~0 < B < 1
$$

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, How about $B>2$, Thanks very much!

Comment: Near $y=0$ your function is equivalent to $1/(D y^B)$ so the integral is not finite if $B \geq 1$.